# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CORS issue when using Vue.js for client side and Express for server side

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, cors, ibm-jazz

I'm trying to make a call to my API on Jazz using Vue.js and Axios, but I am getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jazz.api.com/api/extra_stuff
>   _here' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I've been looking at other solutions like https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html or adding

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
```

to my code and it still didn't work. Even if I do the wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, I still get the CORS issue and cannot call my API. I am using Vue and Typescript for the client side and managed to get Express working for my server side. Here is a code snippet of my Axios API call:

```
return Axios.post('https://jazz.api.com/api/extra_stuff_here', context.getters.getRequest,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
          }
        }
      )
```

This is where I am calling my API in this TypeScript file and here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var publicRoot = './dist';

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use(express.static(publicRoot));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: publicRoot });
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
}); 

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, function() {
    console.log("listening on port 80");
});
```

No matter what I seem to do, I cannot figure out this CORS issue. Before I added express to my application, I still got the same issue, thinking that maybe express on the server side would fix the CORS issue. However it didn't help. Beforehand, I was running my Vue application by doing npm run serve. But any help would be great! Could it possibility be an issue with Jazz?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500226/5188835 - try this solution.

Comment: @CheezyCode just tried and still no luck.. Still getting the CORS issue..

Comment: Remove the Access-Control-* headers from the client code they dont belong there and wont change how the server will handle cors

Comment: Also you dont have a post() route defined in your express code, just a use() and a get()

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay, I removed it! Of course I still get the same issues - any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do I need to have a post()?

Comment: Not sure. Check the actual request in the network tab of the developer's tools. See if it is actually retrieving what it is supposed to, and if it doesnt try adding one

Comment: @PatrickEvans So I took a look at the network tab and it turns out that none of the headers that I set are being read? I'm not sure what this means though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I didn't manage to fix the CORS issue with Axios, but I did manage to find a workaround for this. Instead of using the Axios library, I am using `fetch` to call the API. Since all I need to do with my request call is to pass in parameters and get back data based on the parameters, my application works with `fetch`. While I was doing my research, I saw that there may be issues or limitations using `fetch`? But hey, it works for me so I'll be sticking with this solution. Here is my code as reference for anyone:

```
return fetch('https://dev.jazz.com/api/stuff_goes_here', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(<request object goes here>)
}).then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
  return data;
}).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: How can fetch possible work when Axios doesn't? Don't they do the same thing under the hood?

Answer (score 3):

You’ve added the cors middleware but haven’t enabled it for OPTIONS requests

```
app.options('*', cors())
```

Try adding something like this to your server to enable it.
You can read further in the express docs here 
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: I didn't know that I had to do that. I just tried it, but no luck. I still get the same CORS issue. I'm now wondering if it has something to do with Jazz?